# Execute method when activity shown with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating an android app with fragments.

I already have the skeleton but I want to execute some code when I press a tab button. I mean, I select second tab and I go to the second activity view.

I want to execute and AsyncResponse task and now I have it on onCreateView which I have seen it is executed while populating tabs in the main activity.

Is there any method to execute just when it is shown?  I have checked android developers but I haven't found anything.

This is second tab activity:

```
public class SecondViewActivity extends Fragment implements AsyncResponse {

private String urlServer = "http://url/";
MyTask asyncTask =new MyTask();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    asyncTask.delegate = this;
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondView, container, false);



    asyncTask.execute(urlServer + "TEST.php");

    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void processFinish(JSONArray output) {
    Log.i("TEST", output.toString());
}


}
```

Comment: try to implement your code in onActivityCreated() method in your fragment class.

Comment: onActivityCreated() is executed even before. I tried right now.

Comment: check this. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: @Biribu `onResume` should be appropriate choice in my opinion. so whenever your fragment will be visible then Asynctask will be called.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried but I don't know why it is launched at loading time. And whenever I click that tab, it is not fired.

Comment: I am thinking about this can be done the way I am implementing fragments. This is the tutorial I followed: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/ and I think, doing like this,  create tabs, load activities and keep them in memory all the time not uploading them